# AChartEngine showing only half circle

Tags: android, achartengine, linegraph

[image: This is how value 11 is marked]

This is how any maximum value is being displayed on the graph. How can i ensure that the full point is shown?

Answer (score 1):

Set the Y axis maximum visible value manually:

```
renderer.setYAxisMax(10.5);
```

Comment: but what if the maximum value is something other than 10? ... something like 10000??..

Comment: Just set it to maximum + 1% or so.

Comment: is there any way to get the maximum value from the dataset or should I sort my data to get the maximum value?

Comment: renderer.getYAxisMax()